# while start marathon , exited with status 1

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

```
 24 15:28:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 24 15:28:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 24 15:28:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 24 15:29:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 24 15:29:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: Stopped Scheduler for Apache Mesos.
Jan 24 15:29:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: Starting Scheduler for Apache Mesos...
Jan 24 15:29:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: Started Scheduler for Apache Mesos.
Jan 24 15:29:57 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF marathon[1838]: No start hook file found ($HOOK_MARATHON_START). Proceeding with the start script.
Jan 24 15:29:59 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF marathon[1838]: [scallop] Error: Required option 'master' not found
Jan 24 15:29:59 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 24 15:29:59 ivum01-HP-Pro-3330-SFF systemd[1]: marathon.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

These are the commands I am using for Marathon:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/marathon/conf
sudo cp /etc/mesos-master/hostname /etc/marathon/conf
sudo cp /etc/mesos/zk /etc/marathon/conf/master
sudo cp /etc/marathon/conf/master /etc/marathon/conf/zk
sudo nano /etc/marathon/conf/zk
```

The only portion I need to modify in this file is the endpoint. Change it from /mesos to /marathon.

Answer (score 1):

That’s an out of memory error. Are you sure your node has enough memory to run both Mesos Master and Marathon?

Comment: Thanks ,after clearing I am getting code=exited, status=1/FAILURE ,error .I am using java 8 but still I am facing this .Any idea please share .

Comment: What do you mean by "after clearing"? Also, a `journalctl -u marathon.service -n 200` should give you the log output

Comment: clearing means I removed work directory and logs ..I am getting this logs , [scallop] Error: Required option 'master' not found
marathon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: Also, did you make sure that you have enough mem available, as I already pointed out?

Comment: I have updated details in my question ,Could you please check ?

Comment: You need to set the MARATHON_MASTER env var in /etc/default/marathon to the correct ZK connection string value for your setting